# Derive alternate representation of parametric equations of first quadrant of a circle.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, parametric

In a math book I am reading, the author mentions that the first quadrant of a circle can be defined by the parametric equations
\begin{align*}
x(u)&=\cos{u}\\
y(u)&=\sin{u},
\end{align*}
for $0\leq u\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$.  The author then goes on to say that by setting $t=\tan(u/2)$, one can derive the alternate representation
\begin{align*}
x(t)&=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\\
y(t)&=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},
\end{align*}
for $0\leq t\leq 1$.

Let's consider the function $x$ for a moment.  I understand, that if $t=\tan(u/2)$, then $u=2\arctan{t}$, and $\cos{u}=\cos(2\arctan{t})=(1-t^2)/(1+t^2).$  What I can't see is how this is equal to $x(t)$.  It seems like it should be equal to $x(2\arctan{t})$!  When I actually try to compute $x(t)=x(\tan(u/2))$, I inevitable get stuck and cannot arrive at $(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$.

Can someone please help me to connect the dots here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion is coming from the fact that $x\mapsto x(u)$ and $x\mapsto x(t)$ are not the same function, despite having the same name.  We can be a bit more precise:

Consider $x(u) = \cos u$, and let $u = 2\arctan t$.  Then $$x(u) = x(2\arctan t) = \cos(2\arctan t) = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}.$$  Now, let's define $x_1(t)$ by $$x_1(t) = x(2\arctan t) = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}.$$  In the same way, we can start with $y(u)$ and get to $$y_1(t) = y(2\arctan t) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$  So the functions $x,y$ and $x_1,y_1$ are in fact distinct functions, although we *can* think of $x_1$ and $y_1$ as compositions of $x$ and $y$ with $2\arctan t$.

The important thing here is that
$$x_{1}^2(t)+y_{1}^2(t) = \left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^2 = \frac{1 -2t^2 + t^4 + 4t^2}{1+2t^2 + t^4} = \frac{1+2t^2+t^4}{1+2t^2+t^4} = 1,$$ and so this parameterization does in fact give the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you for that great answer.  As I was typing in my question, I began to suspect the two two $x$'s did not, in fact, represent the same function, and you just confirmed it for me.  Perhaps the author should have been a bit more clear about that.